# Visual Studio resource editor

Tags: file, resources

I am trying to view a .resx file in the resource editor in Visual Studio, but Visual Studio is unable to open it with this program. I right clicked on the .resx file and then chose *Open With*. It gave me a list of different programs I could choose to open my .resx file with, including XML Editor, HTML Editor, Binary Editor and Resource Editor. I chose the Resource Editor and clicked OK. After Visual studio gave me an error message stating: "The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please chose another editor.". How can I make it work?

Comment: The Resource file is not corrupt.

Comment: The .resx file opens up in note pad fine.

Comment: By "corrupt" I don't mean that the file can open in notepad.  I mean that the file structure itself doesn't conform to the .resx spec.  Which might have happened if it was hand edited or edited in a program that doesn't really support that format.. Like notepad.

Answer (score 3):

The [.resx file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ekyft91f(v=vs.100)) is an XML format file. The [.resources file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/zew6azb7(v=vs.100)) is a binary format.

> [Since projects in .NET programming languages do not use resource script files, you must open your resources from Solution Explorer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

The [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-create-a-resource-script-file?view=vs-2019) describes opening [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/7kby2aet(v=vs.100)) in Visual Studio and specifies a .rc file format.

Mads Kristensen wrote a [.NET Resource Editor for .resx files](https://web.archive.org/web/20130816053339/http://madskristensen.net/post/A-NET-resource-editor-application-for-resx-files.aspx).

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [madskristensen.net](http://madskristensen.net/image.axd?picture=resource_editor.png))</sub>

Another alternative (especially if you are using Express and cannot edit for that reason) is the [Canaware DevAssistant program](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=canaware&e=com). It provides a .NET resource editor.

> http://www.canaware.com/Images/en-CA/ResourceEditor_AddImage_289x204.bmp

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an Express edition, may that (the ability to edit a compiled resource) is one of the features that's disabled in Express editions.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new one from the IDE and opening that to see if it's an actual VS problem or if your resource file is corrupted somehow.  I'm going to guess it's the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it .resx is just a textfile, so should be able to open it in notepad to check if it is ok (not corrupt).